# Why is my HTML a tag showing my IP in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My navigation bar a tags show my IP for some unknown reason. I can only assume this is not a very good idea. For example if I inspect my upload a, I can see my IP in the inspector, like this:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('upload') }}">Upload</a></li>
```

Sends the user to http://xx.xx.xxx.x/upload

The route is:

```
Route::get('/upload', 'PagesController@upload')->name('upload');
```

Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: Is that a development environment?

Comment: Check `app_url`

Comment: Suraj, I'm not sure what is that supposed to mean. I am just learning Laravel and hosting my website on my own server. So I guess it is development environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) helper uses `APP_URL` from `.env` file, so change it to something else:

```
APP_URL=http://website.test
```

Comment: If I am hosting my website without a domain name already, will that change anything? Not that it really matters since people on my website can already see my IP anyways since I don't have a domain, but let's say I buy a domain name. Will they still be able to see my IP if I do not change that?

Comment: @Bobimaru yes they will see it if you'll not change it. You can change IP to your domain in the `.env` file when you'll buy one.